# Multirow tables

Tags: tables

I am trying to have `\multirow`s for the first and last columns and following is the closest I could get. Could you please guide me on how to do that (Like the table drawn in Excel below)?

```
    \begin{tabular}{ |l|l|l|l| }
    \hline
    \multicolumn{4}{ |c| }{Convergence} \\
    \hline
    Time & \multicolumn{2}{ |c| }{Information} & Graph \\ \hline
    \multirow{3}{*}{1} & Vertice & 1 & 0.5  \\ \cline{2-1} \cline{3-1}
    & ${P(1)}$ & 0.5 & 0.5 \\ \cline{2-2} \cline{3-2}
    & Chance & 0.5 & 0.5 \\
    \hline
    \multirow{3}{*}{1} & Vertice & 1 & 0.5  \\
    & ${P(1)}$ & 0.5 & 0.5 \\
    & Chance & 0.5 & 0.5 \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please provide a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Answer (score 2):

Haha, got it!

```
\begin{tabular}{ |l|l|l|l| }
  \hline
  \multicolumn{4}{ |c| }{Convergence} \\
  \hline
  Time & \multicolumn{2}{ |c| }{Information} & Graph \\ \hline
    \multirow{3}{*}{1} & Vertice & 1 &  \multirow{3}{*}{1} \\ \cline{2-1} \cline{3-1}
                       & ${P(1)}$ & 0.5 &   \\ \cline{2-2} \cline{3-2}
                       & Chance & 0.5 &   \\

  \hline
    \multirow{3}{*}{1} & Vertice & 1 & 0.5  \\
  & ${P(1)}$ & 0.5 & 0.5 \\
  & Chance & 0.5 & 0.5 \\

  \hline
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: Use only `\cline{2-3}`, not your combination of `\cline`s. Also, your Excel pictures shows a `c`entred horizontal alignment. You can achieve that by using a `|c|l|l|c|` column specification for your main `tabular`.